# Python auto select color bar

Tags: python-2.7, bar-chart, colorbar

I want to set color bar "green" when data direction1 = 005.
How to make it auto select color bar in Python 2.7 from these case?:

```
direction1=['200','250','180','200','300','270','005','080']
time1=['0000','0030','0100','0130','0200','0230','0300','0300']
```

Current script as follows :

```
ind = np.arange(len(time1))
width = 0.50

rects1 = plt.bar(ind, direction1, width, color='r')

for x in range(0,len(direction1)):
    if x in direction1==005:
        rects1[x].set_color('g')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for sharing:

```
values=np.array(direction1)
searchval = '005'
location = np.where(values == searchval)[0]
print location

rects1 = plt.bar(ind, direction1, width, color='r')
for x in location:
    rects1[x].set_color('g')
```

Cheers!!!...